# Time travel story from textbook where a boy explores possible futures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, educational

I think this would have been in one of my textbooks around 1990 or so, 4th to 5th grade material in Kentucky.

A boy gains access to a time machine of the "visit your future self's body" sort. I believe either a parent built it or a scientist met on a field trip. He uses it at least twice to explore career paths. One was as a football player and one as a mechanic. In both, he was dissatisfied. As a player, he was tired, and aching from injuries. As a mechanic, he realized he'd never finished school and was stuck in a dead end job that didn't earn much money.

Finally he talks to the scientist and, I think, comes to the conclusion that the future is not set, that he can be whatever wants, but that he needed to stay in school to maximize his opportunities.

It was a short story, probably under a dozen pages, maybe as few as 2-3.

Comment: Must've been a popular choice.  I recall reading it around the same timeframe in a Washington textbook.

Comment: @Mark: Doesn't surprise me. It very much had a message of "you can be whatever you want" and "stay in school, kids".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[What Are You Going to Be When You Grow Up?](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60358)" by Gregory Benford.  It was published in one of the Harcourt Brace *Treasury of Literature* volumes (and also in the anthology *Spaceships and Spells*).

I discovered that you could search Google Books for schoolbook readers by entering a query that includes

> subject:"Readers"

With [that and some keywords](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=subject:%22Readers%22%20%22time%20machine%22%20football), I found the story.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=VAWtyFwCoJcC&dq=subject%3A%22Readers%22%20%22time%20machine%22%20football&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=190) is another search result showing little parts of the teacher's edition of the book, beginning on page 190, where the story starts.  By entering page numbers and other words in view, I was able to push the small window of viewable area around, enough that I could verify this was the correct story, then find the title and author's name.

Keyword search excerpt:

> 1 6 CHARACTER'S MOTIVATIONS What different motivations have led Mark to choose a career in football? (Accept reasonable responses: He doesn't want to be a garage mechanic; he likes football; having decided on a career makes him feel better and less confused.) inferential: DETERMINING CAUSE-EFFECT 1 7 PLOT: CONFLICT Mark knows it is wrong to use the time machine. What does this tell you about what might happen? Why?

Comment: Thank you! I included an excerpt of the search results, as pulled from what Google pushed back, enough to establish the matching elements. I trust that you are right.